# How to change color depending status from JSON API using flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I Have JSON String Like

```
`[{"name":"Zahid","leads":"0"},{"name":"Nikhil","leads":"0"},{"name":"Rupak","leads":"AB"}]`
```

[image: My Sceeen Look like]

And I will try to change color When lead=> "leads":"0" or any integer value is Blue and lead=>"leads":"AB" is Red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to check before setting color let me show you with an example.

lets just say you are getting your lead value in a variable name lead_value so while setting the color you can place a check like this

```
color : lead_value =='AB' ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in the place where you are writing styles for the text "lead" write the conditional statement

```
text(lead,style:TextStyle(
color: (lead==0)?Colors.blue:(lead==AB)?Colors.red:Colors.black
))
```